# How do I disable firebug from grouping duplicate console output?

Tags: firebug

I notice with the new version of firebug I"m using (1.12.3) it is grouping console output that is the exact same.  How do I disable this?

Ex
[image: Firebug Console]

In the picture above, I would prefer to see:

```
Select Changed
Select Changed
Select Changed
```

Comment: Also, can grouping be disabled in the built-in Firefox developer tools (not firebug)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this topic: https://superuser.com/a/646009/134164

Maybe Firebug should display an option for that in the Console panel.

Florent

Comment: You are right, this shouldn't be an auto on feature, nor should it be difficult to toggle on and off when they change a basic display feature for the user.

Comment: I created an issue for the preference: http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=6871 , though I personally don't agree about disabling it by default. Don't hesitate to star it to vote for it.